# Download data for multiple variables from Eurostat

Tags: r

I have a `variable_list` and a `country_list` that I want to download data for. I'd like to automate that as I don't want to push each download on it's own.

I want the code to iterate through the `variable_list`, download data for the respective `country_list` and store them as `"variable"_data`. I use [get_eurostat](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/eurostat/versions/3.7.5/topics/get_eurostat) for the downloads.

I tried:

```r
variable_list <- list("demo_r_d3area", "demo_r_d3dens", "demo_r_fagec")
country_list <- list("AT","BE","DK")
for (i in variable_list) {
  (assign(paste("data_", i, sep = ""), variable_list[[i]])) <- 
    get_eurostat(id = variable_list, time_format = "num", 
                 filters = list(geo = country_list))
}
```

But I don't think I'm heading into the right direction with that.

Comment: Can you give small examples of the data `variable_list`, `country_list` and `"num"`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I hope I could clear up my question a little. "num" [defines the requested time format as numeric](http://ropengov.github.io/eurostat/articles/website/eurostat_tutorial.html) as the data is mostly annual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the right way to read in the data is with a `lapply` loop into a list.

```
library(eurostat)

variable_list <- list("demo_r_d3area", "demo_r_d3dens", "demo_r_fagec")
country_list <- list("AT","BE","DK")

data_list <- lapply(variable_list, function(v){
  get_eurostat(
    id = v, 
    time_format = "num", 
    filters = list(geo = country_list)
  )
})

names(data_list) <- variable_list
str(data_list)
#List of 3
# $ demo_r_d3area: tibble [156 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  ..$ unit   : chr [1:156] "KM2" "KM2" "KM2" "KM2" ...
#  ..$ landuse: chr [1:156] "L0008" "L0008" "L0008" "L0008" ...
#  ..$ geo    : chr [1:156] "AT" "AT" "AT" "AT" ...
#  ..$ time   : num [1:156] 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 ...
#  ..$ values : num [1:156] 82528 82528 82523 82518 82512 ...
# $ demo_r_d3dens: tibble [90 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  ..$ unit  : chr [1:90] "PER_KM2" "PER_KM2" "PER_KM2" "PER_KM2" ...
#  ..$ geo   : chr [1:90] "AT" "AT" "AT" "AT" ...
#  ..$ time  : num [1:90] 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 ...
#  ..$ values: num [1:90] 93 94 95 95.8 96.2 96.3 96.5 96.6 96.7 96.9 ...
# $ demo_r_fagec : tibble [3,780 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  ..$ unit  : chr [1:3780] "NR" "NR" "NR" "NR" ...
#  ..$ age   : chr [1:3780] "TOTAL" "TOTAL" "TOTAL" "TOTAL" ...
#  ..$ geo   : chr [1:3780] "AT" "AT" "AT" "AT" ...
#  ..$ time  : num [1:3780] 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 ...
#  ..$ values: int [1:3780] 90454 94629 95302 95227 92415 88669 88809 84045 81233 78138 ...
```

---

The data sets can now be accessed with the standard extractor operators. Here is an example of accessing `demo_r_d3area`.

```
head(data_list$demo_r_d3area)
## A tibble: 6 x 5
#  unit  landuse geo    time values
#  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 KM2   L0008   AT     1990 82528.
#2 KM2   L0008   AT     1991 82528.
#3 KM2   L0008   AT     1992 82523.
#4 KM2   L0008   AT     1993 82518.
#5 KM2   L0008   AT     1994 82512.
#6 KM2   L0008   AT     1995 82519.
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this?

```r
for (i in variable_list) {
  variable_list[[i]] <- get_eurostat(
    id = i, 
    time_format = "num", 
    filters = list(geo = country_list)
    )

  assign(paste("data_", i, sep = ""), variable_list[[i]])
}
```

If this is not what you are trying to do, please clearify your question.

Comment: While this suceeds in downloading the data, it also appends it to the initial ```variable_list```, which is not intended.

Comment: Just replace `variable_list[[i]]` with `var_data` twice. Based on your question the intention wasn't clear to me.